# Google Indexing + Yoast SEO Media Attachments

Tags: wordpress, indexing, search-engine, google-search-console, yoast

I have ~300 pages on my website so when I saw my index on Google Search Console, I knew something was wrong. I believe I suffered from the Yoast SEO bug on WordPress (updating from an old version of 7.0) where it created attachment pages for all media that have now been indexed.

I am trying to remove the extra 400+ pages that are now /attachment/ urls and lead to 404's. So far I turned off media attachment url's in yoast.

What is the best approach to removing all of these from my index? Is there any way for Google to do another bulk crawl so I don't have to manually remove all 400+ urls?

Any insight will be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from the official Yoast blog here: [Yoast Blog](https://yoast.com/media-attachment-urls/) they recommend you use the [index purge plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yoast-seo-search-index-purge/) to remove to attachment URL's.

Comment: Sure. Is there a faster way to remove these from my google index or is the manual 'remove url's the fastest way possible? Based on the description of the plugin it says 6 months which seems like waiting for Google to crawl again.

Comment: The recommended way, also by Google. Is to change the HTTP code to a 410 removed. So when Google re-indexes your website it will know you removed those pages. The easiest way to do that is with the plug-in I linked. The re-indexing will not take 6 months as the plug-in suggest, but probably a week or so. If you want to remove the URL's quikly anyways do this: Still install the plug-in so the 410 codes will be added to your attachment URL's. Then use this Google Chrome extension: https://github.com/noitcudni/google-webmaster-tools-bulk-url-removal to bulk remove URL's from Google Index.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "search appearance" category. Then click on "media"

- Redirect attachment URLs to the attachment itself? => no
- Show Media in search results? => off

I think you should not redirect attachment to the parent blog for a reason. The attachment page isn't an equivalent of the parent page. I think it gets stuch in the google index. Consequently, the best solution is to noindex the attachment pages to delete the content of these pages in the Google directory.

Once i have added all my attachment pages to a sitemap. I go the following error:
[image]

This means that for google, the attachment URLs were duplicate of parent pages. This was due to the default Yoast redirection behavior. Therefore, it is better to noindex them. Maybe these redirections can be considered as cloaking by google.